# Python Sniffing code cant find scapy module

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I'm currently doing the SEEDLabs packet sniffing and spoofing lab and the first task asks to use a sniffing program through python using scapy. I have downloaded scapy and yet my program gives:

> ImportError: No module named 'scapy'

I've tried changing the file path of python to python3 and back. I've tried appending the file to multiple different filesystems. no luck yet.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from scapy.all import *

print("SNIFFING PACKETS.........")

def print_pkt(pkt):                       
   print("Source IP:", pkt[IP].src)
   print("Destination IP:", pkt[IP].dst)
   print("Protocol:", pkt[IP].proto)
   print("\n")

pkt = sniff(filter='icmp',prn=print_pkt)
```

I expect to get a screen that has sniffed the selected packets, but if I run the program using `sudo python3 task1.1.py` then I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File :"task1.1.py",line 2 in
>    from scapy.all import * ImportError: No module names scapy

On another note, if I run the program as `sudo python task1.1py` the GUI prints the message and then runs infinitely without any output.

Comment: I apologize in advance about the formatting of the question.

Comment: How did you install scapy ? `pip install scapy` ? Then, yeah, the error will arise, because you installed scapy for `python2` while you are running `python3`. I recommend you use a `virtualenv` like, `python3 -m venv venv && source ./venv/bin/activate && python <yourscript>.py`

Comment: Ive used multiple installations which im sure is an issue, but ive used "sudo pip3 install scapy" and " sudo apt-get install scapy" however it was my understanding that scapy supports python3 now

Comment: scapy does support python3. You have to run the python you install scapy for. I really suggest you use a virtualenv

Comment: I used your virtualenv example but I keep getting errors about it not setting up properly. im using oracle VM to complete this and have completely restarted the machine and reset all of the files. it appears scapy is installed for python and python2 yet when I edit my code I still get the importerror

Comment: Use `python3 -m pip install --user scapy` and run `python3 <script>.py`

Comment: The error message is gone however, only the "Sniffing Packets" line is displayed and what seems to be the code running infinitely as in the insert icon is displayed and not returning to the command line.

Comment: `sniff` will sniff for packets continuously. You should put a limit. `sniff(filter='icmp',prn=print_pkt, count=10) `

Comment: even with the count, the first message is displayed and im left with just the insert cursor. it just doesn't seem like its actually sniffing.

Comment: You are filtering for `icmp` packets, and expecting 10 packets with `count=10`. Try some pings to google.com or something for 2 or 3 times

Comment: Otherwise just use only `sniff(prn=print_pkt, count=10)` to see any 10 packets

Comment: i tried pinging google, got an error message. then i took off the filter and got the same results as the other attempts. the no output is extremely odd